# Ruby command to start/stop delayed jobs from rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

In my project, I am using delayed_job gem. Currently, I can start/end the delayed job from project root with commands

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop
```

How can I run this command from a controller action of a rails project so that I can start or stop the delayed job with html request?

Note: I am on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} bin/delayed_job start"`

`system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} bin/delayed_job stop"`

you can use this and instead of hard coding the environment, it should be written like this

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'system' to run commands inside controller

eg.

```
system "RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start"
system "RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop"
```